# "не вступившее" или "невступившее"

Tags: грамотная-речь, частица-не, частица

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильное написание слова `не вступившее` либо `невступившее` в следующем тексте:

> Исполнитель обязан отменить невступившее в силу решение об одностороннем отказе от исполнения Контракта, если в течение десятидневного срока с даты надлежащего уведомления Заказчика о принятом решении об одностороннем отказе от исполнения Контракта устранены нарушения условий Контракта, послужившие основанием для принятия указанного решения.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос № 250877
как пишется " невступивший в силу закон"
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Верно: **не вступивший в силу закон.**

Таким образом, написание юридического термина подчиняется обычному правилу: раздельное написание НЕ с причастием при наличии **зависимого слова**.